# type(instance.__dict__) is an 'int'?

Tags: python

So I have this code:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 100


class b(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
            return super(b, self).__getattribute__('x')
```

if I run:

```
>>> instance_a = a()
>>> print instance_a.__dict__
```

I get:

```
{'y': 100}
```

But if I run:

```
>>> instance_b = b()
>>> print instance_b.__dict__
```

then I get:

```
100
```

(I expected something like: `{'x':100}`)

So for some reason `type(instance_a.__dict__)` is a `dict`, while `type(instance_b.__dict__)` is an `int`. I'd expect them to be both `dict` types.

Could somebody explain this behavior?

Comment: In `b` you have modified the behaviour for getting attributes to always fetch `x`, hence the value `100`.

Comment: What were you expecting `__getattribute__` to do?

Comment: actually nothing, It was just a code test to see if results matched my expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the following:

```
print instance_a.__getattribute__('y')
```

You will get

```
100
```

Which is essentially what you are doing. You have rewritten `__getattribute__` to ALWAYS return `x`.

Note the following behaviour:

```
>>> instance_a.__foo__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'a' object has no attribute '__foo__'
```

But:

```
>>> instance_b.__foo__
100
```

Comment: Yep, sorry for such a dumb question